# Populating a string with recordId's from selectedRows in lightning datatable include duplicates

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning datatable with checkboxes enabled, and I am trying to get a list of record ID's in a string so that I can use it to prepopulate a call report that it creates with the information from the selected rows.

My event handler for getSelectedData is triggered when a user clicks on a checkbox or more.

```js
        const selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
        for (let i = 0; i<selectedRows.length; i++ ) {
            this.selectedIds += selectedRows[i].Id + ',';    
        }
```

However, I think every time I click on a checkbox this method is called, therefore putting in duplicates of the Id's. How can I ensure there are no duplicates? I tried using a set but it didn't work out well, or I think I used it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a one-liner in JavaScript. By the way, as glls stated, you never reset the string when you add/remove elements, so it gets duplicated every time. Here's the efficient version:

```
getSelectedData(event) {
    this.selectedIds = event.detail.selectedRows.map(row => row.Id).join(',');
}
```

Also note that you probably really just want an Array, not a string of joined values, which is simply:

```
getSelectedData(event) {
    this.selectedIds = event.detail.selectedRows.map(row => row.Id);
}
```

The [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is what allows this to work efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

the reason you are getting duplicates is because you are simply appending id's to a string within an iteration. (your for loop)

you probably want to clear the `this.selectedIds` at the beginning of your method to ensure you don't constantly increase the size of your string and add duplicate info.